# Loading Pandas Dataframe into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to load my data into PostgreSQL. My data is formatted into 2 columns within a pandas data-frame. This is the data-formatted:
Lyrical_data['lyrics_title']['lyrics]

Example:
['lyrics_title'] = ['Some_song', 'Some_song2', 'Some_song3', etc.]
[lyrics] = ['The lyrics to song1', 'The lyrics to song2', 'The lyrics to song3', etc.]

Here we have the data formatted into 2 columns that are associated with each other.
I want to load this data into my PostgreSQL database.

I already initiated psycopg2 for the file, started the connections, and SQAlchemy.

```
import sqlalchemy as db
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

alchemy_engine = db.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:dataEngineer01@localhost:5432/DrakeData')

db_connection = alchemy_engine.connect()

conn = psycopg2.connect(database = 'DrakeData', host = 'localhost', user = 'postgres', password = 'dataEngineer01')

lyrical_data.to_sql('data', con=conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

conn.autocommit = True

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT current_database()')

print(cursor.fetchone())

cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lyrics_table')

command = (''' 
    CREATE TABLE Lyrics_Table (
    Lyrics_Title Text,
    Lyrics Text
)
    SELECT * from lyrical_data
           
''')

cursor.execute(command)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Everything regarding the cursor, creating the table, and selecting the database works, I am having trouble actually inserting the data-frame  into my database.

Comment: what did you try? Show code in question, and full error message

Comment: why do you run `DROP` and `CREATE` at the end? It may remove your data from database and create new empty table in database. You should run `DROP` and `CREATE` before `to_sql`. Or even run `DROP` and `CREATE` only once and remove from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either enable the autocommit before calling `to_sql()`, or manually call `conn.commit()` immediately after, especially if there could ba a transaction already open in that connection. Also, make sure you're populating and inspecting the right table:

```sql
lyrical_data.to_sql('lyrical_data', con=conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

conn.commit()
cursor = conn.cursor()
command = ('''SELECT * from lyrical_data''')
cursor.execute(command)
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

I'm guessing that throughout your attempts

- `to_sql` didn't run a commit on its own and your `conn` doesn't have `autocommit` on by default, so the records weren't visible on the db
- enabling autocommit after the `to_sql` call didn't issue an immediate commit, so the records still weren't visible on the db
- ultimately, the records went to a table named `data`, not something named after the `lyrical_data` dataframe. In the [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) doc you can see the first parameter is the target table name: *`DataFrame.to_sql(name, con, ...`*

  > name : *str*
  >
  > Name of SQL table.

  That doc entry also explains the commit behaviour when given a sqlalchemy connection with an ongoing transaction.